# Laravel 5.3 Class Flash not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

```
FatalThrowableError in RegisterController.php line 104:
Class 'Flash' not found
```

I get this above error saying that the `Class Flash` is not included but I think am including it right what am i doing wrong.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Flash;
```

Comment: Where is your Flash class located ?

Comment: Flash is your model class??

Comment: or you have installed laracasts/flash package ???

Answer (score 0):

Your `controller` should be:-

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;   // change here

use App\Flash; // rewrite this line

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;  // add this line

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
 // stuff here
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers

Your `Flash` `Model` should be:-

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flash extends Model
{
    //
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent

Comment: Thx for the help
But wouldn't my authorization get broken if i changed the namespace?

Comment: Have you used external library for authentication? For laravel authentication check this link:- https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication